# Origin of thread join

Tags: multithreading, naming-conventions

Nearly all programming languages that support threading, have a method called `join`. I understand what a `join` does, but would like to know what the origin behind the naming of it is? Wouldn't a name such as `finish` be more appropriate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thread A and Thread B did different things and now they are going to kind of reunite because their results have to get exchanged - they will join each other, go on and eventually split up again.

Answer (score 4):

I think it comes from the analogy of execution paths.  The program's execution path split into  two separate paths when the thread was spawned, and now you want the two paths to join back together into a single path again.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand/interpret it (although correct me if I'm wrong), threads of execution should all contribute towards a single overall task (if there is no interaction between threads, then they might as well be separate processes, after all one of the main points of threading is to overcome the communication barrier between processes). Therefore it seems logical that subtasks branch off from the overall task and then re-join at a later point, rather than running into a dead end. Also, seeing as when a thread is created it is allocated some of its parents resources, even if the thread does not return a value it should still return what it was given in the first place, thus merging or "joining" with the original thread.